# Magento doesn't send any email except registration welcome message

Tags: magento, sendmail, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

other troubles with magento 1.7 and email sendings, this time on test server (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS), which is able to send only emails for new customer registered. i've checked backend settings and seems that are ok:

Configuration->Advanced->System->Mail sending settings:

- Disable email communications->no
- host: localhost
- port: 25
- Return-Path: yes

all store emails are filled, cache is disabled, a mail agent is configured (sendmail), i've also checked from commad line if it works with:

```
echo "<?php mail('me@mymail.com', 'Test mail', 'This is a test email.'); ?>" | php
```

and it works! Also: also: it's not a gmail issue, i've tried to send to different email provider (gmail and not gmail) with same results

what could it be?

thanks

Comment: Check if there is something in your email server logs (also enable Magento logging and check `var/exception.log`).

Comment: email server log...where? nothing in exception log...

Comment: Already checked existence and content of `/var/log/maillog`?

Comment: @JürgenThelen checked, it's not sendmail but postfix. also seems that mails are sent to myaddress@mymail.org (address configure in backend for Store Mail Adresses and Contacts), which is also the sender address. this is the tailf mail.log while sending email: http://dpaste.com/790426/